# 'ion-header' is not a known element ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Following are the steps i have taken

1. I created a new project of ionic 5 using **ionic start** template blank
2. updated angular to angular 9
3. created a new page module using **ng g page main**
4. listed in AppRoutingModule using lazyloading.

I am getting following error

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/main/main.page.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'ion-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <ion-header>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/main/main.page.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './main.page.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MainPage.
src/app/pages/main/main.page.html:2:3 - error NG8001: 'ion-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress
this message.

2   <ion-toolbar>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/main/main.page.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './main.page.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MainPage.
src/app/pages/main/main.page.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'ion-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3     <ion-title>main</ion-title>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/main/main.page.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './main.page.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MainPage.
src/app/pages/main/main.page.html:7:1 - error NG8001: 'ion-content' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress
this message.

7 <ion-content>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am missing something very obvious.

Following is the code

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/main/main-routing.module').then(m => m.MainPageRoutingModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

main.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MainPageRoutingModule } from './main-routing.module';

import { MainPage } from './main.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    MainPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [MainPage]
})
export class MainPageModule {}
```

main.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sxm-main',
  templateUrl: './main.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.page.scss'],
})
export class MainPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

main.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>main</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but have you tried to turn it off and on again? Had the same problem when generating new components in angular 9. That did the trick..

Comment: @Tomas Vancoillie - this is the first thing that i tried again and again. No luck , i am an angular developer with decent know how. But this error is making me feel stupid.

Comment: You are using the wrong command to create the page.
In ionic, you must use `ionic g page main`, which automatically adds and modifies other associated files.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In my case I was getting weird html template errors including the one OP describes because I created new component and forgot to add it to the module declarations

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
...
declarations: [MyComponent]
}
```

Comment: to avoid such issues, i mostly use angular Cli. But anyways, pointing basic silly mistakes helps a lot to future devs.

Comment: ah see I always use ionic g c my-component . so you just use ng instead ?

Comment: @abhaytripathi do you mean to say that `ionic g c some-component` will not add the component to app.module.ts but `ng` will?

Comment: What a red herring, thank you for this post. I use the CLI, but I'll tell you how I ended up here. I started with the Ionic sample app generated, and refactored the 'tabs' components to my own components. In that process I forgot to redefine the `declarations` which caused all these issues.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and **I simply forgot to add the `IonicModule` to the new module** I created that contained the components throwing the exceptions.

Check to see if all your modules import `IonicModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ExamplePage } from './contactus.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
  ],
  declarations: [ExamplePage]
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

Comment: This solution works for me!
I have shared components and so I created a shared module, and this is where I got the error. And this solution is the correct one, in the shared module add IonicModule. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In your **app-routing.module.ts** instead of *main-routing.module* you should import *main-page-module*.

Instead of this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/yourpage/yourpage-routing.module').then(m => m.YourPageRoutingModule)
  },
];
```

Try this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/yourpage/yourpage.module').then(m => m.YourPageModule)
      },
    ];
```

Comment: this is a correct answer for this particular question, but no one upvotes it because people usually face this error because they forget to import IonicModule =)

Answer (score 3):

Add the name of the component to the declaration part of the nearest `.module.ts` file.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [your-other-modules],
  declarations: [your-component-name-here]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need need to include `IonicModule` in the imports array of your `components.module.ts`

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule, IonicModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting this in case anyone else has this issue, or in case I have the same issue 6 months from now and can't remember how I fixed it.

I had this error in FoobarComponent.  It is part of a library that I was building for reuse in other projects.

Normally when I see an error like this, I check to make sure that FoobarComponent is declared in a module and that the same module imports IonicModule.  Either one of those would cause the compiler (and usually VS Code) to complain.

1. FoobarComponent was declared in and exported from FoobarModule
2. FoobarModule imported IonicModule
3. VS Code wasn't complaining, only the compiler.
4. Other components in the same library were working fine - it was just FoobarComponent that had a problem.

I discovered the issue in foobar/index.ts, where I export all of the Foobar related classes in one place.  It looked like this:

```
export * from './foobar.component';
export * from './foobar.service';
export * from './foobar.models';
```

Notice anything missing?

It turns out that I was not exporting FoobarModule at all.  As a result, when Ivy was doing its tree-shaking step, I guess it was determining that the module was not needed and pruning it.  This explains why VS Code didn't have a problem, since it doesn't tree-shake.

Adding the export to foobar/index.ts fixed the problem:

```
export * from './foobar.component';
export * from './foobar.service';
export * from './foobar.models';
export * from './foobar.module'; // This is the line that was missing
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was not having a route in the Routes object in

> app-routing.module.ts

for one of my pages (some unused map page)

adding:

```
{
    path: 'map',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/map/map.module').then( m => m.MapPageModule)
},
```

made

```
npm run build
```

succeed.

hope this helps someone (upgrading from ionic 5 to 6 and angular 11 to 12).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made a silly mistake.

Importing a Component file despite the need to import a Module into the Router Module caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I ran `npm install` from the terminal. This fixed the issue, the ionic elements are now recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Worth nothing when struggling with this is to make sure you rebuild your app again from time to time after you do changes. For me, answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730027/3280710 was correct but I had to rebuild my app in order for the errors to resolve.

```
ctrl + c
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y

ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I am copy pasting here from a bug report in Ionic 5 that helped me solve my issue:

*I encountered this problem several times - randomly - usually after generating a new component, however the previous -prod builds were successful. Probably it is a build-bug since it happens once in a while wink*

*You probably are trying to open your component/page in a modal window.*

*If yes: Add **YourCustomComponentModule** to the imports list of the ParentModule and your problem will disappear*

*parent.module.ts →*

…

*[
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
IonicModule,
**YourCustomComponentModule**
]
…*

[source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4657#issuecomment-848615468)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed This issue after many days::

This issue back to [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) vs code extension.

1- Update vscode to latest version
2- remove and reinstall  [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

3- Download the `.vsix` file for the release that you want to install from the [releases](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/releases) tab.

*Do not open the .vsix file directly* . Instead, in Visual Studio code, go to the extensions tab. Click on the "..." menu in the upper right corner of the extensions tab, select "Install from vsix..." and then select the .vsix file for the release you just downloaded.

restart vscode will fix your issue as mine

[image]

For more information you can check [ionic froum Topic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-toolbar-is-not-a-known-element-angular-13-ionic-6/222368)

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a solution given to import the component in your `app.module.ts`, my suggestion is never do that. If your project is large or of big size it will cause performance issues because it will override the lazy loading of components.

For those who are looking for a scenario where there is a **parent page** and you need a **child** inside it, so using component is a good idea. But here you will get this error:

```
<ion-element> is not known.
```

To fix this, go to **parent.module.ts** and in declarations it should be

```
declarations:[ParentPage, ChildComponent]
```

And this will remove the error from child component.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened, because my new `module` hasn't been used in any other `module`.

Answer (score 0):

`ionic/cli 7.1` and `@angular/cli 16.0`:

This happened in a component created using `ionic generate component...`. Contrary to before, this command no longer fills up your `app-routing.module.ts` with the path to the newly created component. Adding it manually solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a custom element schema to  yourpage.module.ts

```
 schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

Answer (score -1):

1-) Remove `node_modules` folder and remove the **package-lock.json** file,

2-) Update global angular-cli to latest version,

3-) Validate that TypeScript version doesn't exceed the version supported by Angular (less than 3.8.0),

4-) Run **npm install** on the project and test again!

Comment: tried all that, didnt worked. Later i had to start a new project and cpoied pasted the code, now its working. thanks.

Comment: @abhaytripathi Well, in this case it worked on the client's computer and not yours :P.

Answer (score -1):

Came here because this issue was driving me batty. I followed all the answers on here with no luck. In my case, I had a handful of compile errors. Fixing the other errors magically fixed this. So I'm leaving this tip here for anyone else that has tried everything--fix your other errors first!

Comment: Irrelevant to the question.